# Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.: MongoDB aggregation doesn't let me use $toLower inside a $eq

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I wrote a MongoDB pipeline that has this code in it:

```
  {
    $eq: [
      {
        "$toLower": "HELLO"
      },
      "hello"
    ]
  }
```

And here's a screenshot of it in Mongo Compass

[image: mongo compass]

I am expecting it to simply return true, and "$match" everything (for now).
Eventually I will swap `"HELLO"` with a field name etc.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $match does not accept [raw aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions). Instead, use a [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) query expression to include aggregation expression in $match.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html#pipe._S_match

```
$expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $toLower: "HELLO"
      },
      "hello"
    ]
}
```

[Aggregate command](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H0PtvrFiWfy) [Find method](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kLmOMf0gDDb)